# PLSql return values

Tags: oracle, string, plsql

Here I go again with some PLSql..

I want to know, if there's any way I can use the following function like a select without having to turn it into a function or procedure (so I can see the code from the script where it is contained).

The code would be like:

```
DECLARE
    outpt  VARCHAR2(1000) := ''; 
    flow_rI  VARCHAR2(50); 
    CURSOR flow_r IS
      select flow_run_id
        from table
        where CREATED_DATE < sysdate - 32
        and rownum < 10
        order by 1 desc;
BEGIN 
    OPEN flow_r;
    LOOP 
        FETCH flow_r INTO flow_rI; 
        EXIT WHEN flow_r%notfound; 
        BEGIN 
            outpt := outpt ||  ',' || flow_rI;
        EXCEPTION 
            WHEN no_data_found THEN 
              dbms_output.Put_line(outpt); 
        END; 
    END LOOP;
    dbms_output.Put_line(outpt); 
    outpt := '';
    CLOSE flow_r;
END;
```

The idea is simple, I just want to get a series of codes from my `table` but having the results formatted like `"1234,2434,424,45,767,43"` sort of thing, rather than the table result from a query. It will be used later in the code for various purposes including another queries where I could simply do an `in ([variable with that string])`.

Thing is that using the `dbms_output.Put_line(outpt);`, I can't access it from my application layer and seems that in plsql I cannot use the `return` without turning it into a function.

Would anyone have an idea? It doesn't need to be a PlSql like that as long as I can have the whole code in the script.

thanks!

f.

Comment: ps.: yeah, I know I have a leftover "," in the beginning of the string -_-

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why not use just sql:

```
   SELECT MAX(ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(flow_run_id, ','), ','))
   FROM
   (
    select flow_run_id, rownum rn
    from table
    where CREATED_DATE < sysdate - 32
    and rownum < 10
    order by 1 desc
   )
   START WITH rn = 1
   CONNECT BY PRIOR rn = rn - 1
```

Comment: That my friend, is because I'm too newbie to know beauties like `sys_connect_by_path` :) Thank you very much! Works like a charm. f.

Comment: +1, nice answer, good illustration of CONNECT BY PRIOR. I did try this on a table I have and it doesn't yield the same answer as OP, but I think the concept is correct and I don't have time to debug it.

Comment: ops... I think this would be predictable but I've got this error `ORA-01489` (output string is too long). Well, I reckon it would be better to deal with that in the code, but, just in case, would you have a suggestion for that ?

Comment: @flpgdt, result of sys_connect_by_path can't be more than 4000 char (VARCHAR2 limitation) so if you need longer string, you need have to write function which will be return CLOB

Comment: I see. Vincent gave me a work around with sql (using multiple rows, which solves for me) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975967/max-size-in-a-connected-by-prior-oracle/3976166#3976166 Works pretty awesomely. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if you are on Oralce 11 r2 you can use LISTAGG to do exactly this
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions087.htm

but this site has how you can do it an any version (but you need to be >=9i to do it in pure SQL with 11r2 being ideal):
http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/StringAggregationTechniques.php (specifically look at ROW_NUMBER() and SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH functions in Oracle 9i for a pure sql )

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to define some input/output variables and instead of `return` assign your result value to an output variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple method `WM_CONCAT` as a solution.

```
-- It will show the output in comma separated form
-- you can change the delimiter as well if needed
-- 1234,2434,424,45,767,43
SELECT WM_CONCAT (flow_run_id)
FROM   table_name
WHERE  created_date < SYSDATE - 32
       AND ROWNUM < 10;
```